# Jquery Side Panel (click to close)

Tags: jquery, panel, slide

As you can see, there is a slide panel using jquery who is animated by a hover function. So, I'd like to have a clcik function to open and close this panel. If I replace "hover" by "click" in the code below, the panel opens but I don't know how to make it closing... So the panel stays open...

```
`    
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#slide').hover(function () {
                $(this).animate({left:"-25px"},500);

            },function () {
                var width = $(this).width() -50;
                $(this).animate({left: - width  },500);  

            });

        });
     `
```

(You can see it working on www.zonevolley.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var sliderIsOpen = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slide').click(function () {
        if (sliderIsOpen == false)
            {
            $(this).animate({left:"-25px"},500);
            sliderIsOpen = true;
            }
        else
        {
            var width = $(this).width() -50;
            $(this).animate({left: - width  },500);
            sliderIsOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! That works great! :) So, I have to click the element to close it, but if I want to close the panel by clicking outside this panel, what should the code be???

Comment: so you want it to close it by just clicking anywhere?

Comment: Just for maintainability of code; I'd consider using a boolean for `i`, and perhaps using a more readable variable name (`var sliderIsOpen = false;`?) ... doesn't affect your answer, however. :)

Answer (score 1):

Combination of mine and Mikey's code:
To hover panel to open, and click anywhere to close:

```
var sliderIsOpen = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $sidepanel = $("#slide");

  $sidepanel.on("mouseover.sidepanel", function (e) {
    $sidepanel.animate({left:"-25px"},500);
    sliderIsOpen = true;
  });



  $("html").on("click.anywhere", function(e) {
    if( !$(e.target).is( $sidepanel ) || 
       $(e.target).parents('#slide').length < 1 ) {

     var width = $sidepanel.width() -50;
     $sidepanel.animate({left: - width},500);
     sliderIsOpen = false;

    }
  });

});
```

This says if we put the mouse over the panel, then it should open.
And if we clicked on the page and the target was NOT the `#slide`, OR the parent of what we click on is not `#slide` , then we close it.

The `click.anywhere` is just a way of giving the click event it's own identifier, that way later on we can `$("html").off("click.anywhere");` and not destroy any other event bindings we/plugins may have done :)

EDIT:
I just noticed you are running jQuery v1.3.2 on your website, this code will *not* work with that version, I'm very sorry ... you perhaps should have mentioned that originally. :) the latest versions of jQuery have massive speed improvements. If you cannot upgrade, You'll have to wait a bit so we can convert answers to that version.

Comment: Ok! I understand the code so, what should be the entire code in my situation? I just don't know how to put it right.

Comment: My jquery version: * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.1 Where did you see I'm not using this version?

Comment: Ok! Sorry for this... I'm using 2 versions of jquery on my website... so, the new version is now the only one! :)

Comment: So I tried this code with the new jquery version... It opens on hover but dones'nt close on an "antwhere else click" I think I will let it like that, "click to open" and "click to close" ! :) I like that! :) Thanx a lot!